# dispose multiple kendo-ui dropdownlists

Tags: kendo-ui

I have the following JSFiddle example.  How do I dispose of a KendoUI DropDownList?
http://jsfiddle.net/bryanb/bWRTm/1/

I have tried the following without luck:

```
supplier: <input id="suppliers1" class="suppliers" value="2" />
<br />
supplier: <input id="suppliers2" class="suppliers" value="2" />
<br />
<button id="dispose">Dispose</button>
```

js:

```
function comboboxDispose() {
    $(".suppliers").each(function () {
        var combobox = $(this).data("kendoComboBox"),
            popup = combobox.popup,
            element = popup.wrapper[0] ? popup.wrapper : popup.element;

        //remove popup element;
        element.remove();

        //unwrap element
        combobox.element.show().insertBefore(combobox.wrapper);
        combobox.wrapper.remove();

        combobox.element.removeData("kendoComboBox");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out.  My selector was selecting the wrong elements after my kendoui combobox was initialized. Here is the fix:

```
function comboboxDispose() {
    $("input[class='suppliers']").each(function () {

        var combobox = $(this).data("kendoComboBox"),
            popup = combobox.popup,
            element = popup.wrapper[0] ? popup.wrapper : popup.element;

        //remove popup element;
        element.remove();

        //unwrap element
        combobox.element.show().insertBefore(combobox.wrapper);
        combobox.wrapper.remove();

        combobox.element.removeData("kendoComboBox");
    });
}
```

Working Example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/bryanb/bWRTm/2/